# Can not connect to server during migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

When I try to migrate the database I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I've tried creating a symbolic link to .s.PGSQL.5432 and it does not work. This file for me is in /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432

Does anyone have solutions?

OS - Linux Mint

Answer (score 2):

The `/var/run/postgresql` directory is just the **default** socket location of the postgres client library (libpq) that ships with Debian and the distributions based on it.

The mismatch in the socket location happens when mixing mixing client libraries shipped with the system packages with a server that is self-compiled or from an alternative source.

You may point the client program to the alternate location through the `host` parameter, in `database.yml` (or more generally in the connection parameters wherever they're stored):

```
host: /tmp
```

Notes:

- this must not be the full socket file name, only the directory. Building the file name is the job of the postgres library (libpq), not of the caller.
- the postgres client library understands that this is a path to a server socket as opposed to a hostname because it starts with a slash. Nothing else is needed to indicate a socket. There is no socket parameter in the connection options, unlike with mysql.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was the most logical explanation I've come across for days.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to your `database.yml`

```
socket: /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
```